# Dagger 2, Android 7.0 - Application Instance or Component is null

Tags: android, dagger-2

i get many crash reports from the Play Store from devices using Android 7.0 and 7.1 (no other versions) which I can't reproduce on any of my 7.x devices (and emulators).

Crash:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2659)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2724)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1473)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6123)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:867)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:757)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.package.de.ui.base.BaseActivity.onCreate (BaseActivity.java:53)
  at com.package.de.ui.startup.StartupActivity.onCreate (StartupActivity.java:26)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6672)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1140)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2612)
```

So far so good - a simple NullPointer Exception, but unfortunately its not that simple. (At least for me)

My `StartUpActivity` which inherits the `BaseActivity` looks like this:

```
public class StartupActivity extends BaseActivity implements StartupView {
    private StartupComponent startupComponent;

    @Inject
    StartupPresenter startupPresenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupComponent(MyApplication.get().getAppComponent()); <- Crash
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_startup);

        startupPresenter.bindView(this);
    }

    public void setupComponent(AppComponent appComponent) {
        startupComponent = DaggerStartupComponent.builder()
                .appComponent(appComponent)
                .startupModule(new StartupModule())
                .build();
        startupComponent.inject(this);
    }
```

Also nothing too fancy here.

`BaseActivity:`

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Inject
    protected UserSessionManager userSessionManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyApplication.get().getAppComponent().inject(this); <- Crash
    }
```

So I have a `BaseActivity` which will be injected into the `AppComponent`.

Finally the `Application` class:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

    private AppComponent appComponent;

    private static MyApplication appInstance;

    public static MyApplication get() {
        return appInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        appInstance = this;
        setupAppComponent();
    }

    private void setupAppComponent() {
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .userApiModule(new UserApiModule())
                .build();
        appComponent.inject(this);
    }

    public synchronized AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        if (appComponent == null)
            setupAppComponent();
        return appComponent;
    }
}
```

I know this is a lot of code but I want to make sure you have all the information you need.
I would be more than happy for any suggestions regarding my Dagger2 Setup. There has to be some issue but I can't figure it out.

**edit:**
If anyone runs into this problem. Take a look here: [RuntimeException with Dagger 2 on Android 7.0 and Samsung devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784685/runtimeexception-with-dagger-2-on-android-7-0-and-samsung-devices/46925736#46925736)
This might be your solution.

Comment: did you add this `android:name=".MyApplication"` in manifest file

Comment: Yes I did. Sorry i missed that part.

Comment: Could you include the full stack trace? Usually there is an `attempt to invoke x on a null reference` part with more information

Comment: Unfortunately this is the full stack trace coming from the play console.